# WkWebview javascript animation froze when screen locked

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, wkwebview

Xcode 12.3 iOS 12.4+ iPhone Application

I have a view controller which contains wkwebview which gets initialized on startup. This is on the framework side. An enclosing app adds this view onto their view controller as a subview. The app is purely HTML and javascript-based app. We render HTML pages based on user interaction. Everything works fine except for an issue with the Lock Screen

On a particular screen, there is some animation running while updating some values on the screen as well. When the app is moved to the background, the app runs fine but when I Lock the Screen and come back to the app, the animation and all processing on the screen are frozen. I would have to start the process back from the home screen.

I noticed that both moving to background and lock screen have the same state changes such as did enter the background and will enter foreground but in one case, everything is frozen. Could someone please let me know what might be the problem and what would be a solution in this scenario?

Thank you.

Edit

This is the animation called on the html page...the screen is expecting some values which is sent from framework once done processing

```
let showNextItemJS = """
              function startNextAnimation() {
               var box = document.querySelector('\(boxElement)');
                    if(box) {
                    var thisItem  = box.querySelector('\(diagnosticItem)');
                    var statusStr = '\(statusStr)'
                     if (thisItem) {
                         thisItem.classList.add('start');
                         if (statusStr != 'none') {
                             thisItem.classList.add(statusStr);

                         }
                     }
               } else {
                    var thisItem  = document.querySelector('\(diagnosticItem)');
                    var statusStr = '\(statusStr)'
                     if (thisItem) {
                         thisItem.classList.add('start');
                         if (statusStr != 'none') {
                             thisItem.classList.add(statusStr);
                         }
                     }
                }
               
            };
                
            function stopLastAnimaation() {
                var box = document.querySelector('\(boxElement)');
                if(box) {
                    var lastItem  = box.querySelector('\(lastDiagnosticItem)');
                    if (lastItem) {
                        lastItem.classList.add('finish');
                    }
                } else {
                    var lastItem  = document.querySelector('\(lastDiagnosticItem)');
                    if (lastItem) {
                        lastItem.classList.add('finish');
                    }
                }
            };
            
            startNextAnimation()
            stopLastAnimaation()

    """
 
    callJavaScript(showNextItemJS)
```

Comment: Seems the situation is very detailed but not easy to help because there isn't codes which have the problem. Other people would help well if there is code of the animation the screen is freezed.

Comment: I have added some code...hope it helps...this is the main javascript code which updates the value on the screen. As values keeps coming in, it stops animation and updates value and starts animation until processing is done